# Combinatorics- The number of ways to arrange marbles

Tags: combinatorics

There are R red marbles, G green marbles and B blue marbles $(R \leq G \leq B)$ Count the number of ways to arrange them in a straight line so that the two marbles next to each other are of different colors.

I can't solve the general problem.
But if $B \geq R+G+2$ the answer is $0$. 
If $R=G=B=2$, the answer is $30$. 
I have tried using recurrence, but I have no ideas up to now.

Comment: Define $r (R, B, G)$ to be the number of ways of arranging them where the first marble is red. Define $b( R, B, G), g ( R, B, G)$ respectively. Can you set up the recurrence with these terms? (Note: Forget the condition $ R \leq G \leq B$ for now)

Comment: @Calvin Lin But how many ways to put a Green Marble into B+G+R-1 Marbles? We don't know the order of them

Comment: Note that we defined what the first color of the line is, so we could add marbles to the start of the line while following the instruction of "two marbles are of different colors". So, can you write $ r(R, B, G)$ in a linear recurrence with terms like (say) $ g ( R, B, G - 1), r ( R-1, B, G ) , \ldots $?

Comment: Is there a formula for $R=G=B$ ?

Comment: @Calvin Lin, setting up the recurrence is very easy, but how can we find the general formula. It is a set of 3 functional equations